# Use company name to find exact linkedin url

Tags: javascript, python, google-api, linkedin-api

Let's say I have 10 company names.
How to find their "nearly-exact" linkedin url?

ex.
A company is named "ABC Corp", its' linkedin url might be "https://www.linkedin.com/company/abc-corp"
but it's not accurate.

There's a way to improve the precision by use google to search linkedin+company name to find the result, but the error rate is still high.

is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The link you'd fetch would be `https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=COMPANY_NAME_HERE` which searches for the company name.

Then, you can use beautiful soup to scrape the first result which is usually the company you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

## To do this via web/iOS/Android.

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/3881/find-an-organization-s-page-on-linkedin?lang=en

1. Type the company, university, or high school name into the Search bar at the top of your LinkedIn homepage.
2. Click Companies or Schools at the top of the search results page.
3. Click Locations, Industry, or Company size to filter the results for a company. (optional)

Click on the correct organization name in the results list that appears.

## To do this via the API

I'm assuming this is what you're looking for.

LinkedIn marketing API provides an Organization Search API for this use case. You can search using just keywords by calling the search API.

eg:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search?q=companiesV2&baseSearchParams.keywords=LinkedIn%20Corporation`

However, if you happen to know information like the company's region/industry/company size etc. you can specify those as `facets` (think of these like filters)

eg:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search?q=companiesV2&baseSearchParams.keywords=LinkedIn%20Corporation&companySearchParams.facetIndustry%5B0%5D=6&companySearchParams.facetCompanySize%5B0%5D=H&companySearchParams.facetCompanyCountryRegion%5B0%5D=us:84`

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-search